# How to create absolute route from an unknown but relative base path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have a micro-frontend application being loaded into one of several different host apps via Module Federation using webpack. The MFE is agnostic to its hosting app, by design, but through Module Federation, the react router is shared between the host and the MFE.

This means that the MFE could be hosted at one of 2 potential routes, like this:

```html
/container/project/<pId>/users
/container/subscriptions/<sId>/project/<pId>/users
```

though theoretically more routes could be added in the future, and I'm looking for a solution that is future-proof, so for practical reasons, the MFE does not know what its base-path is (only that one *likely* exists).

Within the MFE, there are a series of base routes, along with nested routes. Something like this:

```html
/new
/all
/invite
/<uId>
/<uId>/contacts
/<uId>/projects
/<uId>/subscriptions
```

What I would like to be able to do, is have a series of navigation links for the top-level routes (`new`, `all`, and `invite`) that act as base-routes *relative* to this MFE, but whenever I try to do that, they end **routing from the root of the entire application**. So a link like this `<Link to="/new"/>` will route the user to `https://application.com/new` *instead* of `https://application.com/container/project/<pId>/users/new`

And if I of course can't use a relative link, since the url within my MFE could be at various different hierarchical levels. So a relative link like this `<Link to="../new"/>` would result in these navigations, depending on where the user is

```html
/invite           =>    /new
/<uId>/contacts   =>    /<uId>/new
```

the second example there being of course very wrong.

Is there a way to create an anchor point within the react router tree that can act as a base path for my MFE, so that I can wrap my MFE in this anchor point and treat all absolute routes *relative* to that anchor point?

Comment: `<Link to="new/" />` should do that. Has absolutely nothing to do with React, though. It's [HTML 101](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#linkTypes).

Comment: Hmm. @tao Is there any documentation on adding a `/` to the end of a navigation link that you could link me to? I tried that and I'm seeing no noticeable difference between `<Link to="new/" />` and `<Link to="new" />`

Comment: I have a hard time finding official documentation on how to build a relative vs absolute link. It's common knowledge, but I can't find an official standard. As per the ending `/`, on most servers there's no difference, but on some it won't load `new/index.html` unless you point to `new/`. So, does not having the starting slash achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: I see. I guess the issue I'm running into regardless of if I'm using `new` vs `new/`, is that if I'm on the `<unknownBasePath>/<uId>/contacts` page and I click the link for `new`, it takes me to `<unknownBasePath>/<uId>/contacts/new` when I wanted to go to `<unknownBasePath>/new`

Comment: I see, in that case you want to use the [<base href="unknownBasePath">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag and `<Link to="/new" />`.

Comment: Unfortunately per the original question, "unknownBasePath" is _unknown_ and variable to my application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256086/discussion-between-tao-and-whelch).

Answer (score 0):

I may have had a bad react component structure; my navigation links were being rendered *outside* of the react routes, but by rewriting the structure and leveraging nested routes and the `<Outlet/>` component, I think I effectively accomplished my goal - the navigation links are now all relative to their current location within the router tree structure, which is what I wanted in the first place!

so now `<Link to="new"/>` properly always routes to `<unknownBasePath>/new` no matter where it's clicked from!